# Material UI class names in production do not resolve correctly

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, production, jss

#### Current Behavior

Class names generated by `makeStyles` in production break functionalty that apparently works correctly in development mode.

The `&` (nested) operator breaks in production cause the unique identifier in classnames do not match.

#### Simple example

1 - Development Mode :white_check_mark:

**1.1** Inspecting `<head>` tag, the generated styles:

- Custom `makeStyles` generation in my component:

[image: Captura de pantalla 2020-07-22 a las 1 20 01]

**1.2** The classnames rendered by MaterialUI:

[image: Captura de pantalla 2020-07-22 a las 1 19 16]

*(Ignore additional properties, there are informative without functionality)*

**1.3** The matched styles inspected in chrome:

[image: Captura de pantalla 2020-07-22 a las 1 19 46]

The match its correct and correctly override the styles.

This WORKS

[image: Captura de pantalla 2020-07-22 a las 1 25 50]

The expected `scale` of `transform` is correctly overridden.

2 - Production Mode :x:

**2.1** Inspecting `<head>` tag, the generated styles:

- Custom `makeStyles` generation in my component:

[image: Captura de pantalla 2020-07-22 a las 1 36 32]

*(Obiously is the same that in development)*

**2.2 -** The classnames rendered by MaterialUI:
[image: Captura de pantalla 2020-07-22 a las 1 33 56]
*(Ignore additional properties, there are informative without functionality)*
They have all a random postfix.

**2.3** The matched styles inspected in chrome:

[image: Captura de pantalla 2020-07-22 a las 1 42 07]

The classname `.makeStyles-root-304.MuiInputLabel-marginDense` generated by `makeStyles` does no match in the MaterialUi label cause the identifier `.MuiInputLabel-marginDense-220`. Ends with `220` in the label HTML node, when in the generated `makeStyles` has not `220` postfix

Do not match. This DO NOT WORKS

[image: Captura de pantalla 2020-07-22 a las 1 32 03]

Style is not overridden

#### Expected Behavior

In production mode, the identifiers can be matched with a variable os something.
Maybe I am mistaken hard, but I don't know why this is caused.

#### Steps to Reproduce

I write a simple example of what i am trying, you can check a Codesandbox example **working correctly** (Codesandbox as development environment) in
https://codesandbox.io/s/simbleapp-1xzgd?file=/public/index.html

To **check the issue I am posting** its needed be in a production like environment, then just download the same Codesandbox at your local and:

```
npm install --production
npm run build
npm run start:prod
```

I am just trying to do a simple library wrapper of material for my projects, and I found this issue casuality checking the production App cause in development i never face that behaviour.

#### Your Environment

"Core library" dependencies

```
@material-ui/core  v4.11.0  
@material-ui/styles  v4.10.0  
React   peer     
Browser   Chrome     
TypeScript  3.7.3
```

"App" dependencies

```
React 16.13.0     
Browser Chrome
```

Comment: its probably the most descriptive question **I**'ve ever saw

Comment: Are you using StrictMode?

Comment: @RyanCogswell Yes, and do not warnings or aditional/related info its shown

Comment: Does it have the same problem without StrictMode?

Comment: In general, your approach with `generateBundleMaterial` looks problematic. This is calling `makeStyles` during render which is not how it is intended to be used. When driving styles off of props, the props should be passed in to `useStyles` (i.e. the hook returned from `makeStyles`) and used in the style rules -- they should not be used to generate a dynamic `makeStyles` call. `makeStyles` should be called at the top-level (i.e. executed only once -- not once per render).

Comment: @RyanCogswell I think finally found the solution, its related to the derterministic or non deterministic class names in Material UI https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#with-material-ui-core https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#class-names.
Thx anyway, if finally i solve the issue i will repply myself

Comment: Yep, totally right, is just for test. i have it out of component in my project itself, the codesandbox its a fast copypaste to show the issue how works